# Image slider with modal prev/next buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootply:  `http://www.bootply.com/byUX0u7K0s`

css:

```
.modal-body img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
```

JS:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  $('.modal-body').html(  $(this).parent().html() );
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/2.3.1/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/2.3.1/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/2.3.1/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
  </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>



<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above code i had implemented carousel with popupmodal in bootstrap.everything works fine in the code but when i open a model popup i want to use prev and next button in popup also.had anyone came accross this.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with only bootstrap framework, please check some additionl plugin, like this

http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery

And use it like this

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <a href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="" data-toggle="lightbox">
                <figure>
                    <img src="//25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_400.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <figcaption>@gregfoster</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="http://distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/85c5d0e4039411e3bd9b22000aa82186_7.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="">
                <img src="//distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/85c5d0e4039411e3bd9b22000aa82186_7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="" data-toggle="lightbox">
                <figure>
                    <img src="//25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_400.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <figcaption>@gregfoster</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8900/

Comment: Have you added css and css and call the plugin?